# Unable to create linked server from SQL Server 2008R2 to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a couple of databases in Azure  and added them to an Elastic Pool.
I am able to create a linked server on SQL Server 2017. The issue I am faced with is when creating the linked server to Azure SQL i get the following screenshot error:

[image]

Can Anyone guide me on how to go on about this as I am a newbie to Azure SQL. I have read the following article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/f90fd20b-e9e1-42a1-a7ad-647e4c55afb1/linked-server-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database?forum=sqlgetstarted

Yet i can't seem to sort that out.

Much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191740/cannot-connect-to-sql-azure-using-a-linked-server  This should help. Should be pretty quick.

Comment: @Ramakant Dadhichi I don't think MSDASQL  is supported in Azure SQL .

Comment: This is definitely possible and we have done it before. SInce 2008 R2 moved out of support we don't have any in our estate to show some screenshots. This should do the trick : https://mitchwheat.com/2016/06/16/sql-server-create-a-linked-server-from-an-on-premise-sql-server-to-sql-azure/

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi. Thanks for the tips, it worked a treat.
Can I ask is there a way of creating a linked server from Azure SQL elastic pool to query SQL server on premises?